# How to change status or notify based on timings in Jenkins with JMeter tests?

Tags: jmeter, jenkins

We're using the Performance Plugin running JMeter tests in Jenkins.  I'm looking for some way to change the status and/or notify when tests run slower.  Is there another plugin I could use?  Any ideas how to proceed with modifying or writing my own Jenkins plugin if none provide the functionality I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved this by using [JMeter's Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) as a child to the HTTP Request I wanted to time setting the Duration to Assert in milliseconds to the longest time allowable and Appy to as Main sample only.  When this time is exceded the assert fails and the test gets marked as failed.

[image: Duration Assertion]

PAGEUNDERTESTTIMEOUTMS would be set in User Defined Variables or one could just enter timeout value.

Comment: Hi @EGHM, could you give a bit more information about how using the Duration Assertion fixed your problem? That way, anyone else with the same problem will have a better guide to what they need to do.